# how to differ values of same session in different browser tab in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, web-config, session-state

i am creating one web application and there is a requirement where i have to differ values of same session `Session["JobNumber"]` on different browser tabs. if i make any changes in first tab, these changes should not affect second tab.

i have searched it for this and found same answer in all blogs and SO answers so i tried this :

in web.config file

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState cookieless="true"
      regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

on form's page load

```
if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                PageID.Value = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
.

.

}
```

here `PageID` is:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="PageID" runat="server" />
```

code where i store value in session

```
var sessionkey = string.Format("Session_{0}", PageID.Value);
            Session[sessionkey] = SelectedNumber;
            Session["JobNumber"] = Session[sessionkey];
```

this is what i found everywhere so i tried this. but its not working. instead when i `log in` to my app pop up comes with message **`error:401`**. if i remove that code from `web.config`, this error will disappear.

as `401` is for authentication failure. how the code i have written in web.config relate to that? and strange thing is, pop up message comes saying `error:401` still i logged in successfully. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Page Load:

```
PageID.Value = Session["JobNumber"].ToString();
```

where ever using Session["JobNumber"] , replace it with `PageID.Value`

No need of this code in `web.config`

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState cookieless="true"
      regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```